# Read data from csv in puppeteer script and pass data to some website for auto filling forms also upload images on other sites via puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Please help me out I want to write a script in puppeteer that can Read data (image url's/path) from CSV file and can pass data to some other website to auto filling/submitting forms.

Note: I want to write down a script which can read the Images URL's from the CSV and can upload those on some site form means images will be uploaded by puppeteer script is this doable? Please guide me I need your help on this.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Yes puppeteer can upload files to a website. Now, because here we *help* people who write their programs themselves (rather than write programs *for* them), please show what you have done already and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: What did you try?